# Mercurial .hgignore for Android Studio projects

Tags: android, mercurial, android-studio, hgignore

What files should be ignored in Mercurial when using Android Studio (1.0 RC4 Windows) for development?

Creating new application project also creates `.gitignore` file. I have translated that to following `.hgignore` file

```
syntax: glob
.hgignore
.gradle
local.properties
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
build
```

But when I do `Add to VCS` for my project, some files that are not in ignore list are not being added to Mercurial. Files left out are:

```
.idea\.name
.idea\compiler.xml
.idea\copyright\profiles_settings.xml
.idea\encodings.xml
.idea\gradle.xml
.idea\misc.xml
.idea\modules.xml
.idea\scopes\scope_settings.xml
.idea\vcs.xml
build.gradle
MyApplication.iml
gradle.properties
gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.jar
gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties
gradlew
gradlew.bat
settings.gradle
```

Should I add those files to ignore list, or should I add them to VCS?

It is also unclear what should be done with `.iml` files. Adding project to Mercurial using AS will add `app\app.iml` file, but adding project to Git using AS will leave that file untracked.

I don't want to track superfluous files in VCS, but I don't want to miss storing important ones. There are numerous sources on which files should be tracked, but information differs so greatly it is hard to make any definite conclusion.

**Update:** final version of my `.hgignore` file

```
syntax: glob
.hgignore
.gradle
local.properties
.idea
.DS_Store
build
*.iml
gradlew
gradlew.bat
```

For sharing project among developers following files have to be commited to VCS or AS will not be able to import project on another machine:

```
gradle.properties
gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.jar
gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties
```

Comment: I suggest you not ignore the .hgignore file itself.  You don't want to have to recreate it if you load the project on another machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you add all the files listed above to `.hgignore` except for the `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle`. The files in `.idea` directory are generated automatically by `Android Studio` and you shouldn't track them, or manually edit. I don't think you will ever need to edit `gradlew` or `gradlew.bat` so you can ingore them also. You can add `gradle.properties` and `gradle-wrapper.properties` later, when you will need to change the default versions (personally, I've these two to ignore also).

Answer (score 7):

This is what I ended up with for gradle based Android Studio (1.5) projects:

```
syntax: glob
*.iml
.gradle
.idea/dictionaries
.idea/libraries
.idea/tasks.xml
.idea/workspace.xml
build
gen
local.properties
```

I think this is a very complete list.
The only questionable option *imho* is whether you ignore `*.iml` files or not.
They duplicate information from `build.gradle`, are automatically generated and constantly updated by Android Studio, but on the other hand new developers will need to "Import project" instead of "Open an existing Android Studio project" if you decide not to track them.

Contrary to the other answer, I would strongly recommend checking all the gradle wrapper files into VCS.
The wrapper's purpose is to bootsrap the installation of gradle.
If you for example want to set up automatic builds, you only need to check out the project, create `local.properties` or corresponding environment variables and execute `gradlew assemble`.
The build system will then automatically install the gradle version specified in your `gradle-wrapper.properties` to perform the `assemble` task. This is valuable information to share.

Also check this official JetBrains Support article: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827587-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems

Answer (score 3):

By dint of [.ignore](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7495) plugin you can generate `.hgignore` just in two clicks. Open the context menu on a root folder, select 'New >> .ignore file >> .hgignore'. Then for Android Studio project simply tick the checkboxes (templates) listed below:

- Android
- Gradle (optional)
- JetBrains
- AppEngine (optional)

Add `syntax: glob` to the top of the generated file.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA mercurial .hgignore file for regular gradle / maven java multi project including wrappers (wrappers also should be committed)

```
syntax: regexp
.gradle/*
.idea/*
syntax: glob
.git/*
*/out/*
*/build/*
*/target/*
.DS_Store
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
*.log
```