# What files should I be ignoring in Subversion for an Android Studio project?

Tags: android, svn, android-studio

I found some previous references, with a link to

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore

Which does have a good list of file types and I've added them to svn:ignore.

However, there's still tons showing up in my Subversion commit dialog, and I have a feeling they should be ignored.

I have a tons of subfolders and files in app/build/intermediates, as well as build/intermediates. There's also a .idea folder. Some .iml files which I think are project related...

Thanks!

(This is my svn:ignore so far)

`*.apk
*.ap_
*.dex
*.class
bin/
gen/
.gradle/
build/
/*/build/
local.properties
proguard/
*.log`

Comment: You can also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27311746/mercurial-hgignore-for-android-studio-projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ignore any .iml and .idea things. Those are specific to your machine, so if you work in a team others will just over write them. The rest looks pretty good. As for the build folders I ignore them an all their sub folders.

Comment: Can I ignore all the gradle files?

Comment: You shouldn't ignore the build.gradle or settings.gradle, but the other should be ok to ignore.